# Compressing Images in Iphone programmatically from NSData

Tags: iphone, image, uiimageview, compression, nsdata

I wish to compress the image before storing it as an `NSData` object.

Below is the code, that helps me take `NSData` object of an Image.

```
NSURL *referenceURL = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL];
        ALAssetsLibrary *library1 = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
        [library1 assetForURL:referenceURL resultBlock:^(ALAsset *asset)
         {

             int byteArraySize = asset.defaultRepresentation.size;

             NSMutableData* rawData = [[NSMutableData alloc]initWithCapacity:byteArraySize];
             void* bufferPointer = [rawData mutableBytes];

             NSError* error=nil;
             [asset.defaultRepresentation getBytes:bufferPointer fromOffset:0 length:byteArraySize error:&error];
             if (error) {
                 NSLog(@"%@",error);
             }
             rawData = [NSMutableData dataWithBytes:bufferPointer length:byteArraySize];
}
```

Any Help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

UIImagePickerController does return a compressed image, but you can control the format and compression as well with this built in UIKit function and a related function for PNGs:

```
NSData* UIImageJPEGRepresentation(UIImage *image, CGFloat compressionQuality);
```

You might need to create an NSURL if referenceURL returns a string.

```
NSImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: referenceURL]];
NSData *compressedImage = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, .1); //.1 is low quality
```

Comment: There are EXIF details in the image, I cant compromise with them.Will this method cause any harm to my EXIF data. ?

Comment: I am not sure.  Try it out real quick and let us know.

Comment: i am new to Iphone , how can I use this method? Help Please.

Comment: Edited answer to give a little detail.  To test it out you could write the compressed image to a file in the simulator and open it in an image editor.

Comment: EXIF data will be lost, because UIImage can't retain this data.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a UIImagePickerController, the image returned will be a JPEG, which is already compressed (I think).  If not, you can use AVAssetWriter to write the image as a JPEG or PNG.

Comment: I wish to compress this image upto 100 Kb, as of now its 1 Mb.

Comment: Is resizing the image an option?

Comment: There are EXIF details in the image, I cant compromise with them.Will this method cause any harm to my EXIF data. ?

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure about EXIF data.  It may be possible to extract it, manipulate the image, and then put it back in before writing. But I have no idea how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

simple to use:-

```
    -(UIImage *)fireYourImageForCompression:(UIImage *)imgComing{
NSData *dataImgBefore   = [[NSData alloc] initWithData:UIImageJPEGRepresentation((imgComing), 1.0)];//.1 BEFORE COMPRESSION
int imageSizeBefore     = (int)dataImgBefore.length;


NSLog(@"SIZE OF IMAGE: %i ", imageSizeBefore);
NSLog(@"SIZE OF IMAGE in Kb: %i ", imageSizeBefore/1024);



NSData *dataCompressedImage = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imgComing, .1); //.1 is low quality
int sizeCompressedImage     = (int)dataCompressedImage.length;
NSLog(@"SIZE AFTER COMPRESSION  OF IMAGE: %i ", sizeCompressedImage);
NSLog(@"SIZE AFTER COMPRESSION OF IMAGE in Kb: %i ", sizeCompressedImage/1024); //AFTER

//now change your image from compressed data
imgComing = [UIImage imageWithData:dataCompressedImage];


return imgComing;}
```